# Java Date Problem while exporting on excel page

Tags: java, excel, date, date-format

I am exporting report to excel from .jsp. The date viewed on jsp is in "2010-06-30" format.
I want the exact format on excel, but it got changed automatically to "6/30/2010" format on excel file. I also tried by using java.util.Date API, still unable to get same format date on excel.

Comment: What do you use for Excel generation? Show us some code.

Comment: How are you exporting to excel? POI?

Answer (score 2):

> but it got changed automatically to "6/30/2010" format on excel file

What is the default format of dates in excel? This is most likely the reason.